# Supporting multiple content encoding in .net Framework 4.6.1 using mailkit

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit

I'm working on building an email client using .net framework 4.6.1, which will fetch emails from a mailbox and display on the email client. Currently I'm using s22.Imap's `ImapClient.GetMessage()` method to retrieve the email content. It works fine for the attachments and for bodyContent with most default encoding.

But some of my mails are of type `CodePage = 932` and `EncodingName = "Japanese (Shift-JIS)"`. I'm not able to fetch these emails since they throw `System.NotSupportedException` for most of the BodyEncoding attributes / properties.

On Searching through the github issues for s22.Imap, there was an [issue](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap/issues/125) which was suggesting to use mailkit instead of s22.Imap. I would like to know more about how this encoding part is handled in mailkit. Also would like to know if there is a default way to handle encoding of unknown CodePage types.

Comment: Why not just try MailKit and see how it works? If you want a technical explanation of how it works, I don't have the time - read the source code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read this blog post that explains what most C# MIME parsers get wrong and why MimeKit can handle multiple charset encodings.

https://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2013/09/time-for-rant-on-mime-parsers.html
https://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-decoding-rfc2047-encoded-headers-is.html

## Time for a rant on mime parsers...

Warning: Viewer discretion is advised.

Where should I begin?

I guess I should start by saying that I am obsessed with MIME and, in particular, MIME parsers. No, really. I am obsessed. Don't believe me? I've written and/or worked on several MIME parsers at this point. It started off in my college days working on Spruce which had a horrendously bad MIME parser, and so as you read farther along in my rant about shitty MIME parsers, keep in mind: I've been there, I've written a shitty MIME parser.

As a handful of people are aware, I've recently started implementing a C# MIME parser called [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit). As I work on this, I've been searching around on GitHub and Google to see what other MIME parsers exist out there to find out what sort of APIs they provide. I thought perhaps I'll find one that offers a well-designed API that will inspire me. Perhaps, by some miracle, I'd find one that was actually pretty good that I could just contribute to instead of writing my own from scratch (yea, wishful thinking). Instead, all I have found are poorly designed and implemented MIME parsers, many probably belong on the front page of the [Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

I guess I'll start with some softballs.

First, there's the fact that every single one of them was written as `System.String` parsers. Don't be fooled by the ones claiming to be "stream parsers", because all any of those did was to slap a `TextReader` on top of the byte stream and start using `reader.ReadLine()`. What's so bad about that, you ask? For those not familiar with MIME, I'd like for you to take a look at the raw email sources in your inboxes particularly if you have correspondence with anyone outside of the US. Hopefully, most of your friends and colleagues are using more-or-less MIME compliant email clients, but I guarantee you'll find at least a few emails with raw 8bit text.

Now, if the language they were using was C or C++, they might be able to get away with doing this because they'd technically be operating on byte arrays, but with Java and C#, a 'string' is a unicode string. Tell me: how does one get a unicode string from a raw byte array?

Bingo. You need to know the charset before you can convert those bytes into unicode characters.

To be fair, there's really no good way of handling raw 8bit text in message headers, but by using a `TextReader` approach, you are really limiting the possibilities.

Next up is the `ReadLine()` approach. One of the 2 early parsers in [GMime](https://github.com/jstedfast/gmime) ([pan-mime-parser.c](https://github.com/jstedfast/gmime/blob/GMIME_0_7_0/pan-mime-parser.c) back in the version 0.7 days) used a `ReadLine()` approach, so I understand the thinking behind this. And really, there's nothing wrong with this approach as far as correctness goes, it's more of a "this can never be fast" complaint. Of the two early parsers in GMime, the pan-mime-parser.c backend was horribly slow compared to the in-memory parser. Of course, that's not very surprising. More surprising to me at the time was that when I wrote GMime's current generation of the parser (sometime between v0.7 and v1.0), it was just as fast as the in-memory parser ever was and only ever had up to 4k in a read buffer at any given time. My point is, there are far better approaches than `ReadLine()` if you want your parser to be reasonably performant... and why wouldn't you want that? Your users definitely want that.

Okay, now come the more serious problems that I encountered in nearly all of the mime parser libraries I found.

I think that every single mime parser I've found so far uses the "String.Split()" approach for parsing address headers and/or for parsing parameter lists on headers such as Content-Type and Content-Disposition.

Here's an example from one C# MIME parser:

```
string[] emails = addressHeader.Split(',');
```

Here's how this same parser decodes encoded-word tokens:

```
private static void DecodeHeaders(NameValueCollection headers)
{
    ArrayList tmpKeys = new ArrayList(headers.Keys);

    foreach (string key in headers.AllKeys)
    {
        //strip qp encoding information from the header if present
        headers[key] = Regex.Replace(headers[key].ToString(), @"=\?.*?\?Q\?(.*?)\?=",
            new MatchEvaluator(MyMatchEvaluator), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        headers[key] = Regex.Replace(headers[key].ToString(), @"=\?.*?\?B\?(.*?)\?=",
            new MatchEvaluator(MyMatchEvaluatorBase64), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    }
}

private static string MyMatchEvaluator(Match m)
{
    return DecodeQP(m.Groups[1].Value);
}

private static string MyMatchEvaluatorBase64(Match m)
{
    System.Text.Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7;
    return enc.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(m.Groups[1].Value));
}
```

What?! It completely throws away the charset in each of those encoded-word tokens. In the case of quoted-printable tokens, it assumes they are all ASCII (actually, latin1 may work as well?) and in the case of base64 encoded-word tokens, it assumes they are all in UTF-7!?!? Where in the world did he get that idea? I can't begin to imagine his code working on any base64 encoded-word tokens in the real world. ‍♂️

I'd just like to point out that this is what this project's description states:

A small, efficient, and working mime parser library written in c#.
...
I've used several open-source mime parsers before, but they all either
fail on one kind of encoding or the other, or miss some crucial
information. That's why I decided to finally have a go at the problem
myself.
I'll grant you that his MIME parser is small, but I'd have to take issue with the "efficient" and "working" adjectives. With the heavy use of string allocations and regex matching, it could hardly be considered "efficient". And as the code pointed out above illustrates, "working" is a bit of an overstatement.

Folks... this is what you get when you opt for a "lightweight" MIME parser because you think that parsers like GMime are "bloated".

On to parser #2... I like to call this the "Humpty Dumpty" approach:

```
public static StringDictionary parseHeaderFieldBody ( String field, String fieldbody ) {
    if ( fieldbody==null )
        return null;
    // FIXME: rewrite parseHeaderFieldBody to being regexp based.
    fieldbody = SharpMimeTools.uncommentString (fieldbody);
    StringDictionary fieldbodycol = new StringDictionary ();
    String[] words = fieldbody.Split(new Char[]{';'});
    if ( words.Length>0 ) {
        fieldbodycol.Add (field.ToLower(), words[0].ToLower().Trim());
        for (int i=1; i<words.Length; i++ ) {
            String[] param = words[i].Trim(new Char[]{' ', '\t'}).Split(new Char[]{'='}, 2);
            if ( param.Length==2 ) {
                param[0] = param[0].Trim(new Char[]{' ', '\t'});
                param[1] = param[1].Trim(new Char[]{' ', '\t'});
                if ( param[1].StartsWith("\"") && !param[1].EndsWith("\"")) {
                    do {
                        param[1] += ";" + words[++i];
                    } while ( !words[i].EndsWith("\"") && i<words.Length);
                }
                fieldbodycol.Add ( param[0], SharpMimeTools.parserfc2047Header (param[1].TrimEnd(';').Trim('\"', ' ')) );
            }
        }
    }
    return fieldbodycol;
}
```

I'll give this guy some credit, at least he saw that his `String.Split()` approach was flawed and so tried to compensate by piecing Humpty Dumpty back together again. Of course, with his String.Trim()ing, he just won't be able to put him back together again with any level of certainty. The white space in those quoted tokens may have significant meaning.

Many of the C# MIME parsers out there like to use Regex all over the place. Here's a snippet from one parser that is entirely written in Regex (yea, have fun maintaining that...):

```
if (m_EncodedWordPattern.RegularExpression.IsMatch(field.Body))
{
    string charset = m_CharsetPattern.RegularExpression.Match(field.Body).Value;
    string text = m_EncodedTextPattern.RegularExpression.Match(field.Body).Value;
    string encoding = m_EncodingPattern.RegularExpression.Match(field.Body).Value;

    Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);

    byte[] bar;

    if (encoding.ToLower().Equals("q"))
    {
        bar = m_QPDecoder.Decode(ref text);
    }
    else
    {
        bar = m_B64decoder.Decode(ref text);
    }                    
    text = enc.GetString(bar);

    field.Body = Regex.Replace(field.Body,
        m_EncodedWordPattern.TextPattern, text);
    field.Body = field.Body.Replace('_', ' ');
}
```

Let's pretend that the regex pattern strings are correct in their definitions (because they are god-awful to read and I can't be bothered to double-check them), the replacing of '_' with a space is wrong (it should only be done in the "q" case) and the `Regex.Replace()` is just evil. Not to mention that there could be multiple encoded words per field.Body which this code utterly fails to handle.

Guys. I know you love regular expressions and that they are very very useful, but they are no substitute for writing a real tokenizer. This is especially true if you want to be lenient in what you accept (and in the case of MIME, [you really need to be](http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-decoding-rfc2047-encoded-headers-is.html)).